# Flutter: Target of the URI does not exist

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio

I cant import a dart package to another dart package despite specifying the correct path

I tried to close the project and reopen and still the error would not go away

I tried looking up some more solutions to the issue and tried all of that but could not fix the issue

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `utils` directory must be inside the `lib` directory only,
and will used without the `package` keyword.

And your `main` file will import it like below

```
import 'utils/dimensions.dart';
```